# Speeding up docker on Mac with docker-sync

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to speed up a build on Docker for Mac using docker-sync. It takes about 20 minutes to build on Ubuntu, but upwards of 2 hours on a Mac.
I just wanted to go through the workflow to see if it makes sense.

command after the sync has started? Or should all the information in the docker run command above be put into the docker-sync yml files and then I just start the first two docker-sync commands?
Would love some clarity on this. Thanks!

I’ve got a docker run command to start docker that looks like this :

> sudo docker run --privileged --mac-address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -h=“0000000000” -ti --user root --rm -v ~/local/path/to/files/:/path/to/files/on/docker/env

In order to get docker-sync going, I have made a docker-sync.yml file, a docker-compose.yml and a docker-compose-dev.yml, described below.

I had a few questions.

Do I need to run

> docker-sync start

and then

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d

and then run my

> sudo docker run --privileged --mac-address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -h=“0000000000” -ti --user root --rm -v ~/local/path/to/files/:/path/to/files/on/docker/env
>
> version: “2”
>   syncs:
>   simplest-sync: #tip: add -sync and you keep consistent names as a convention
>   src: ‘./[unique name of folder containing all source code on local Mac machine]’

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

> version: “2”
>   services:
>   app-simplest:
>   image: alpine
>   command: [‘watch’, ‘-n3’, ‘cat /var/www/index.html’]

my docker-compose-dev.yml looks like this :

> version: “2”
>   services:
>   app-simplest:
>   volumes:
>   - /path/to/local/Sourcefiles/on/Mac:/path/to/files/on/docker/env
>   volumes:
>   simplest-sync:
>   external: true

I want to be able to eventually enter my docker container and execute the build in the /path/to/files/on/docker/env. It takes a very long time now, and I wish to speed it up. In its current configuration, there is no change to the speed using docker-sync.

Comment: What other differences do your Ubuntu and Mac systems have? Does building in Ubuntu in a VM run faster on your Mac than on the Mac natively?

Comment: the build runs much faster on an ubuntu host. the ubuntu version is 18.04 and the Mac probably higher or the same amount of hardware performance specs. Mac is running MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Could be the version of Docker used. [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)?

Comment: I am using Docker Desktop for Mac... version 19.03.2